# can't delete table row with jquery-confirm.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery, and one of my first tasks was to make a dynamic table. I managed to create a button that deletes the table row on click and it worked perfectly, the problem is, when i added a confirmation box for the user, and assigned the function to remove the tr to it, it stopped working.

i've tried several things inside the button function, but it seems like either way the button only closes the alert box and the tr remains untouched.

//This works just fine, it deletes the selected tr without any issue
but it needs a confirmation from the user

```
$(document).on('click','.delete', function(){
$(this).parents('tr').remove();
}
```

//This is my code for the confirmation box including the shown function in the action for the button

```
$(document).on('click','.delete', function(){
    $.alert({
        useBootstrap:false,
        columnClass: 'small',
        title: 'Are you sure you want to delete the task?',
        content: 'This action is irreversible',
        type: 'red',
        typeAnimated:true,
        icon:'fas fa-exclamation-triangle',
        typeAnimated: true,
        buttons: {
            Delete: {
                text: 'Delete',
                btnClass: 'btn-red',
                action: function(){

                    $(this).parents('tr').remove();

                    $.alert({
                        title:'Task deleted',
                        icon:'fas fa-exclamation-triangle',
                        type:'red',
                        content:'',
                        useBootstrap:false
                    });
                }
            },
            close: function () {
            }
        }
    });
});
```

To sum it up, i understand how to delete the tr with .remove(), but i don't understand why it doesn't work inside the alert function. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register the `click` event,  you are registering it to an element or elements with the class of `.delete`. Therefore, inside the click handler function, `this` refers to the element that was clicked.

When you are inside the `.alert` function of jquery-confirm, `this` refers to a different element  (probably the button in the dialog, depending on how jquery-confirm is implemented), so the parent of that element is not the `tr` that you are looking for.

Try assigning `$(this)` to a variable before you make the call to `$.alert`, like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.delete', function(){
    var buttonClicked = $(this); //assign to a variable here
    $.alert({
        useBootstrap:false,
        columnClass: 'small',
        title: 'Are you sure you want to delete the task?',
        content: 'This action is irreversible',
        type: 'red',
        typeAnimated:true,
        icon:'fas fa-exclamation-triangle',
        typeAnimated: true,
        buttons: {
            Delete: {
                text: 'Delete',
                btnClass: 'btn-red',
                action: function(){

                    buttonClicked.parents('tr').remove(); //reference that variable here

                    $.alert({
                        title:'Task deleted',
                        icon:'fas fa-exclamation-triangle',
                        type:'red',
                        content:'',
                        useBootstrap:false
                    });
                }
            },
            close: function () {
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer, not only it solved the problem but i understood perfectly what the issue was, have a nice day.